# How do I add Android to an iOS application in the Instabug admin pages?

Tags: instabug

I currently have an instabug application set up to monitor our iOS app.  I can create a new application and select both iOS and Android there, but I don't see an option to start tracking Android from our existing iOS application.

How can I add Android to our current ( iOS ) application on Instabug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single instabug application tracks either an Android application or an iOS application, you can't tracking both using a single app.

When creating a new application and choosing both iOS and Android that internally creates 2 different apps, one for iOS and one for Android.